# show java version on docker logstash

Tags: java, docker, logstash

Context: There is a need to bump the Java version that logstash image is running on. I was hoping that bumping the logstash image version would give the needed java version bump (desired outcome is bump to java 11.0.12 or greater), but I don't know how to even check what version of java is running.

Currently using the docker image `docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.14.2`, but how to check java version?

Following https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/11907, I tried this:

`docker run --rm -it docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.14.2 java -version`, but this is the result:

`/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint: line 14: exec: java: not found`

however, running `docker run --rm -it docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.9.0 java -version` gives the following output:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.9.0
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I don't understand why a logstash docker version `7.9.0` recognizes `java -version` command, but not `7.14.2`. I tried `7.10.0` and `7.11.0` etc., seems to be the same and cannot check. How can I check java version for logstash version beyond `7.9.x`?

Comment: Check out the logstash `Dockerfile` how it starts logstash. Maybe it uses a start script. Take a look at the start script, how it searches for and starts Java. Use the same Java command for your interactive terminal to get the Java version.

Comment: I'd like a little more guidance please. I checked inside the containers, and when I go into the container shell (`docker run ... sh`), and `ls`, I see that in 7.14 there's a `jdk` directory, whereas not for 7.9

Comment: It sounds like java is not on the PATH. You could also check to see if JAVA_HOME is set with `echo $JAVA_HOME`. Or search with `find` instead of `ls`; it must be in some subdirectory, I imagine.

Comment: The `Dockerfile` is not inside the container. It is the source of the generated image. There you find all the information about the image. One important piece of information is how logstash is started. Then you know where the JDK is located inside the container and you can start it yourself to get the version information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 7.10 Logstash uses a [bundled java](https://www.elastic.co/blog/whats-new-logstash-7-10-0), this is why you can run the `java` command when using the 7.9 docker images and not when using version above that.

Until version 7.9, the docker image installed java using `yum` which makes the `java` binary available globally in the container because its location is exported in the `PATH` environment variable.

From version 7.10 java is not installed through `yum` as the bundled java is used, so the `java` binary is not available in the `PATH` environment variable.

You will need to run the full path to the `java` binary, which should be `/usr/share/logstash/jdk/bin`.

Comment: thanks! This did it!:
`export PATH="$HOME/jdk/bin:$PATH" `